# Bot joining voice channel then leaving instantly Discord.Net

Tags: c#, .net, audio, discord, discord.net

In Discord.Net 1.0.2, I am trying to make a bot which can play youtube videos in voice channels. The problem is when the bot joins, the bot instantly leaves. Here is my code.

```
    [Command("play")]
    public async Task PlayMusic(string videourl)
    {
        #region Joining the channel
        SocketGuildUser user = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
        if (user.VoiceState == null)
        {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(":x: You aint' in a voice channel!");
            return;
        }
        ISocketAudioChannel channel = user.VoiceChannel;
        await channel.ConnectAsync();


        #endregion 
    }
```

I don't have any errors. As a bonus, how do I play audio files?

Comment: Not having any errors doesn't necessary means that there are no errors. Try to add a `Try{} Catch{}` block and see if it catches any errors.

Comment: You are not playing anything thats why it leaves or it could be wrong packages. Your code should be just fine. For playing songs you could take a look at the documentation of Disocrd.Net or DiscordSharpPlus, they got some guides on it.

Comment: Ok, when I look at these guides, I usually get confused at the FFmpeg part... What do I do?

Comment: What do you mean by you get confused?

Comment: Ok, it says to install ffmpeg, yet I don't know how to, so how do I?

Comment: I bet there are about 1k + videos on youtube just search for Install ffmpeg windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord.NET - Bot immediately disconnects after joining voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589407/discord-net-bot-immediately-disconnects-after-joining-voice-channel)