# Streaming MP3 to Discord.net 2.0 - audio is super-fast (chipmunk). Ideas?

Tags: c#, naudio, discord.net, system.io.file

I am using a mashup of examples found online to send the audio from a MP3 file to a discord channel via Discord.net 2.0 (c#).

It took forever to get any audio at all to send... and now that I at least get that working, the audio is super-fast - like chipmunks on speed.

As background, while I am using a static mp3 file here, I will actually be using the google cloud text to speech engine to generate the stream ill be sending - but wanted to get it working with a known file first.

I am not new to developing, but I am new to working with audio of any kind. I understand how audio works - and in this case the problem should be one related to the bitrate, but that does not seem to be the case as I manually set the bitrate of the stream to the bitrate of the file (and I have tried changing it to no effect).

Furthermore, I am supremely confused about the while loop you will see in my code below. I have never used a while loop like that... though it does seem to work, though I can't for the life of me figure out why, since the variable in the condition does not seem to change. I feel like I am missing something very simple and just can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried just about every block of code related to this that i can find on the net, as well as numerous iterations of my own code thrown in. None have been successful.

'''

```
bool playing = false;
                 AudioOutStream dstream = null;
                CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

                try
                {
                    var reader = new Mp3FileReader(path);
                    var naudio = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader);                    
                    dstream = client.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Voice, 32000);
                    playing = true;            
                    await naudio.CopyToAsync(dstream,50);                    
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    if (e.InnerException != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
                }

                while (!playing) ; 

                Console.ReadLine();
                cancellationToken.Cancel();
                Debug.WriteLine("Pre-Flush");
                dstream.Flush();
                Debug.WriteLine("POST-FLUSH");
```

'''
The code above is the "nuts and bolts" of the streaming code. There is a lot more above and below related to it, but mostly channel/guild management and cleanup, command handling etc.

This block of code was purported to be working by another stackoverflow post, but I suspect it was for discord.net 1.0, which may be why I have an issue.

This code DOES play the file, but so fast that it is incomprehensible. The file contains approx 4 seconds of audio, but it plays in a fraction of a second. After it finishes playing, it never exits the while loop, which at least makes sense to me. That said, without the while, or modifying the while to attempt to detect when the stream is finished, have all failed. This is the only way i can get any audio at all to play.

The expected result would be for the audio to play at the right bitrate and then exit and flush as expected.

Any kick in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you have all the libraries loaded correctly? This is a common cause of audio problems in discord bots.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589407/discord-net-bot-immediately-disconnects-after-joining-voice-channel/49645548#49645548) is an answer I posted for another question.

---

These are a few things I pulled from the official Discord API guild.

Windows 64-bit: https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/natives/vnext_natives_win32_x64.zip
Windows 32-bit: https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/natives/vnext_natives_win32_x86.zip
FFmpeg for Windows: https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/natives/index.html#ffmpeg-for-windows

Other OS's:

- GNU/Linux: https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/articles/vnext_setup.html#gnulinux-1
- OS X: https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/articles/vnext_setup.html#mac-os-x-1
- FreeBSD: https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/articles/vnext_setup.html#freebsd

Note for D.NET users: You need to rename libopus.dll to opus.dll before use, otherwise audio client will still complain about missing libraries.

[image: Binary Flowchart]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the bitrate of the audio you're sending ? 
This is a problem I had while creating the stream. I was sending the wav data too fast and created that chipmunk voice. You have to make sure the data you read from your audio file and the data you send to the Discord AudioStream are strictly exactly the same.